# SQL to_date function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

im modifying an oracle table using the following line of code:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO "+dbOwner+"tbl_name VALUES('" + id+ "','" + studID+ "','"+"TO_DATE('"+ dateStr +"','MM/DD/YY)");
```

dateStr value: 2014-04-25

```
           var now = new Date(),
        dateStr = now.getFullYear() + "-",
        monthCode = now.getMonth() + 1;

    dateStr += ((monthCode < 10) ? ("0" + monthCode) : ("" + monthCode));
    dateStr += "-" + ((now.getDate() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getDate()) : ("" + now.getDate()));
```

Comment: Im getting a DB error, im unable to update db table.

Comment: what is the text of the error?

Comment: Error adding new record into database

Comment: Is it the Oracle Error text or your own message? Also, it seems you missed a quotation in your sql. It should be db.execute("INSERT INTO "+dbOwner+"tbl_name VALUES('" + id+ "','" + studID+ "','"+"TO_DATE('"+ dateStr +"','MM/DD/YY')");

Comment: Why don't you first print the query in your code, this way you can find out the problem in query and after that you can try the same in oracle just to be sure.

Comment: Seems, there is also a missing "." after the dbOwner, i.e. should be ".tbl_name VALUES...."

Answer (score 0):

use bind variables. your insert statement will be 'visible'. there would be no problem to add quotes for variables (it will be automatic). and bonus: it is safer and faster.
Also, you can pass date as date, without transformation to/from string.

It will not work only for schema name (dbOwner).

Answer (score 0):

according to what you write in the question

dateStr value is: 2014-04-25

so you should modify the date format in your code to be:

yyyy-MM-DD